# Upsert with multiple query criteria

Tags: mongodb

I have a user object which contains a username, email address and a version, which is incremented each time the user is saved. When saving the user to Mongo the update query includes the version, in the case where a user has been modified on the database before they are saved the version will be different and so the user will not be saved.

An example update query:
`{"username":"name","version":6}`

In some cases I want to use an upsert when I save the user using `update`, as their account may not be created at that stage. In a case where the account has been created and modified since it was loaded then from my understanding it will try and create a new document as the query doesn't match any documents. Is there a way to only create a new document if a specific field of the query doesn't match, for example the username?

Comment: [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let us have the username as 'newUser1' and the collection as 'users'

Execute the following in mongo shell

if(!db.users.findOne({username: newUser1})) { db.users.insert({username:newUser1, email:abcnewuser1@gmail.com, version:1}) }

Note: We need to provide the exact username

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem statement is that

1. if some other process have already updated your record then the code shouldn't update it because the version passed (in memory) is lower than the one already existing (recently updated by previous process) in database.
2. however, if the version passed is equal to the one already existing the max version then it should update.
3. and if the version passed is strictly greater, then it should insert the record.

You can use the below code to achieve it but this is not a very elegant solution in production environment as its not happening within an statement and hence atomicity is not guaranteed. Might not be very elegant for prod like environment but you can build on top of it as per your requirement.

```
--in the variable userToUpdate, change the version to 0, 1 and 2 to see different types of behaviors as explained in the above 3 points.

db.t1.drop(); //drop if exist
db.t1.save({uname:"sachin", v:0, email:"email-0"});
db.t1.save({uname:"sachin", v:1, email:"email-1"});
//----
var userToUpdate = {uname:"sachin", v:2, email:"email-2"};
//----
var user = userToUpdate.uname;
var cur = db.t1.find({uname:user}).sort({v:-1}).limit(1);
var latestVersion = 0;
if(cur.hasNext()){
    var v1 = cur.next();
    latestVersion = v1['v'];
    printjson('latestVersion='+latestVersion);
}

versionToUpdate = (userToUpdate.v < latestVersion)? -1 : userToUpdate.v;
if(versionToUpdate != -1){
  printjson('Going to upsert');
  db.t1.update( {uname:user, v:versionToUpdate}, userToUpdate, {upsert:true} );
}else{
printjson('latest version in db : '+latestVersion+', which is greater than the passed    version '+userToUpdate.v+', hence ingoring');
}
```